# How to include CSS relative to context path in JSF 1.x?

Tags: jsf

How can I include CSS stylesheets relative to context path in JSF 1.1?

```
<link href="{CONTEXT}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Like we use in [JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template).

```
<link href="#{resource['css:styles.css']}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

Depends on the view technology being used:

If JSP(X), use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`:

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

If Facelets 1.x, use `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}`:

```
<link href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

If Facelets 2.x, use `#{request.contextPath}`:

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

---

Note that there's *no* support for `#{resource}` nor `<h:outputStylesheet>` in JSF 1.x.

Comment: #{request.contextPath} returns nothing.

Comment: Are you using Facelets or JSPX? When you said XHTML I assumed it to be Facelets. In JSP(X) you should use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead. I edited the answer.

Comment: Tnx for your response. I am using facelet. I have resolved the issue by using #{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, I'm using Facelets 2.3. `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}` works. But `#{request.contextPath}` does not; it returns empty string. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JSF 2.2 with mojarra 2.2.

> `#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}`

solves the problem for me; I was using a facelet (.xhtml).